# Querying the size of the PostgreSQL partitioning range

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have the below query which shows me the partitioned table names in a PostgreSQL database. But I need to define which table in this list is partitioned with which range?

For example, this query finds out for me 2 tables, `table1` and `table2`.

As I know, my `table1` is partitioned per day, and `table2` is partitioned by month.

How can I update the query to show me which table is partitioned by which range?

```
SELECT pt.*, pc.relname AS partitioned_table_name
FROM pg_partitioned_table pt
         JOIN pg_class pc ON pt.partrelid = pc.oid;
```

Comment: The partitioning constraint is not stored on the partitioned table, but on the partitions (`pg_class.relpartbound`). Each partition could in theory have a different range: one could span a day, the next one could span a week. If you *know* that all partitions have the same size of range, you could query an arbitrary partition and measure the size of its range.

Comment: I need only name of partitioned main table with info weekly or daily partitioned

Comment: Right. My comment tried to tell you that that is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I am clear. Thank you very much for dedicated time